# Repository insert with navigation property throws 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'

Tags: entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm using EF Core and sqlite. Given following 1-to-1 entities:

```
  public class Entity1:FullAuditedEntity<int>
  {
    public Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

  }

  public class Entity2: FullAuditedEntity<int>
  {

    public string Name { get; set; }       

    [ForeignKey("Entity1Id")]
    public Entity1 Entity1{ get; set; }
    public int Entity1Id { get; set; }
  }
```

and following insert logic:

```
    entity1.Entity2 = new Entity2();
    entity1= await entity1Repository.InsertAsync(entity1);//entity1Repository is of type IRepository<Entity1>
```

Code above throws:

**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException : An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
---- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException : SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.
   at  ...**

This approach doesn't work either, throws the same:

```
    var entity2 = new Entity2();
    entity1.Entity2 = entity2;
    entity2.Entity1 = entity1;
    entity1= await entity1Repository.InsertAsync(entity1);//entity1Repository
```

What I'm doing wrong, what I'm missing? What is the correct way to create Entity1 and Entity2 with  Entity2 property being set? Is it possible to create with Entity1 repo only?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**: Problem solved. In actual code entity2 has it's own reference on entity3, which is obvoiusly was throwing. It was the cause.

Comment: You insert a  `Entity2` without any reference to an `Entity1`. You shouldn't be surprised you get a foreign key violation.

Comment: I think you have the ForeignKey attribute reversed.  I think it should go the int column (i.e. Entity1Id) like `[ForeignKey(nameof(Entity1))] public int Entity1Id { get; set; }`.

Comment: Also, a 1-1 relationship: Have you considered using inheritance to map that?  Like Entity2 : Entity1?

Comment: @GertArnold: Thank you for reply. Following code, which I also tested have the very same exception:
var entity2 = new Entity2();
entity1.Entity2 = entity2;
entity2.Entity1 = entity1 ;

Comment: @LeeRichardson: Thank you for reply. According to this reference(https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/foreignkey-attribute) I have case 2. As of inheritance -- this two classes have nothing to do with each other. It is just for simple demonstraion. I need to create Entity2 by default when I create Entity1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
public class Entity1:FullAuditedEntity<int>
{
   public Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; } = new Entity2();

   public string Name { get; set; }    
}

var entity1 = new Entity1();
entity1 = await entity1Repository.InsertAsync(entity1);//entity1Repository
```

Or do you want to clone? Check out:
https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/48873716/how-to-deep-clone-copy-in-ef-core

Comment: Thank you for reply.  No, no cloning. The first your approach is correct, the very same thing. I did as you suggested and still "foreign key" issue. Maybe it has smth to do with type of repository (IRepository<Entity1>)?

Answer (score 0):

See update in my post -- there was other entity which violated fk constraints. Thanks everyone for your time.